# Strip src attribute value from php variable containing youtube iframe string

Tags: php

Can any one please either advice or point me in the right director for how to strip strings out of strings.

In my case I have this variable.

```
$videoEmbed = the_sub_field('video_embed_code');
```

which is essentially this string (example)...

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2RR-tzGOyi0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

My question is can the src attribute value be extracted? But using php and not javascript.

Any pointers or help would be most awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
<?php 
$videoEmbed = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2RR-tzGOyi0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($videoEmbed);

$src = $doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');

echo $src;
//http://www.youtube.com/embed/2RR-tzGOyi0
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using PHP, one way of doing is,

```
<?php

$iframe_code = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2RR-tzGOyi0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>';
$root = simplexml_load_string($iframe_code);

echo $src = $root['src'];

?>
```

**Demo:** http://codepad.org/UEaNfo1A

Comment: Thank you that works great - but only if the $iframe_code varible is string. If I use a php function like this  `get_sub_field('video_embed_code');` - it does not work weirdly. But if I `echo get_sub_field('video_embed_code');` - that echos an iframe string. Very odd.

Comment: I'm doing it like this...  `$iframe_code = get_sub_field('video_embed_code');`